# How to establish a testing environment in local IIS to test ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, iis

I've created a ASP.NET MVC web application in Visual Studio, and right now I can test it locally on my own IIS, then later on I upload it to the server for other users to access. But I want to know is it possible for me to establish a testing environment using IIS so that I can test the website without actually uploading it to the server?

Comment: Isn't that what you're doing when you mention "and right now I can test it locally on my own IIS"?

Comment: You can always create your own testing environment for sure.  Just do it.

Comment: It is very important to set up a testing environment to mirror your final production environment, so even though you can open your local IIS to others, I would suggest you keep doing what you do right now.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply! I'm still a bit confused about where to start tho...

Comment: nvm I understand it now thanks again